# benefit of using [md5] over [trust] authentication for local Unix sockets

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am following a PostgreSQL installation guide that advises (subsequent to installing the database for the first time), to setup a password for the `postgres` user:

```
alter role postgres password '<<super-secret-password>>';
```

... and then change the `pg_hba.conf` file so that the line for local (Unix) sockets reads:

```
local all all md5
```

...  instead of:

```
local all all trust
```

It would seem to me that this only adds an extra layer of defense but for somebody to take advantage of `local all all trust` he would first have to gain access to the local machine, right?

**Question 1:** do I understand correctly that if access to the local machine is password protected (UNIX password) then there should be no worries over a `local all all trust` ?

Also, the same guide additionally recommends that a `.pgpass` file is located in my home folder (I guess for backup scripts that cannot be prompted for a password). The password is stored clear-text in that `~/.pgpass` file:

```
echo 'localhost:5432:*:postgres:<<super-secret-password>>' > .pgpass
chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass
```

**Question 2:** So, what is the benefit of using `md5` and not `trust` for local sockets? If one gains access to local machine, he can also read the `.pgpass` file. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Question 1**: using md5 auth for local connections is particularly helpful when you have a multi-user machine, or if you might add additional user accounts for friends/family/coworkers/whoever someday.

If you are and will remain the only actual user on your system, there is less benefit, but it could still be useful: suppose some bad guy manages to break into some system account like 'www'. He may not be able to do a whole lot from that account without root privileges. But if you've left your pg_hba.conf open to 'trust' all local users, the bad guy can do anything to your database, probably including taking over the 'postgres' user account as well, and moving on to attempt to root your system, steal your data, or whatever from there.

For **Question 2**: You could use a .pgpass file with, say, only a 'readonly' user's credentials, so if a bad buy took over that account he wouldn't have superuser-level access to the database. If you do store the password for the postgres user in your ~/.pgpass, then yes, it would be "game over" for your postgres instance if a bad guy took over that local user account. Again, that documentation was written with the possible use-case of a multi-user machine in mind, e.g. different local users might have or use various Postgres user accounts, not necessarily superuser accounts.